# How can I redirect in ASP.MVC when an Ajax request is made?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I would like to redirect to another page within an action method when for instance a certain exception occurs or authorization fails. This is not a problem with normal requests, however when the request is made via Ajax, redirection fails. 
Many folks out there seem to suggest that I should send back a `JavaScriptResult` and change the `document.location`, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution. Are there any alternative ways to achieve this? Thanks.

P.S. I am using ASP.NET MVC v1.0.

Comment: are you wanting the page that made the request to be changed?  or the destination of your AJAX request?  If you wnt the browser to change the answer below is the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do a "redirect" via AJAX is with javascript, whether you pass back a JavaScriptResult with a script that sets the location or the new URL in JSON and set the location in the callback handler.  I think the choice really depends on how you would handle the result of the request otherwise.  If it's always going to redirect, I would simply make the request without AJAX.  If normally, you'd return HTML that gets put on the page, then a JavaScriptResult may be better.  If you're typically getting JSON and updating the page via code, then I'd send back a JSON response containing the URL and let the callback handler set the location.

Comment: Thanks. The JavaScriptResult option seems to be a sort of hack, so I'll go with the JSON option, which looks clearer.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to do the same and this url was a big help for me.  I modified it slightly so that it would work with RedirectResult as well as just Redirect.

http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-ajax-redirect/

Just have all of your Controllers inherit from this base Controller.

```
 public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller {

            protected override RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToRoute(string routeName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues) {
                return new AjaxAwareRedirectResult(Url, routeName, routeValues);
            }

            public class AjaxAwareRedirectResult : RedirectToRouteResult {
                public AjaxAwareRedirectResult(UrlHelper url, string routeName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
                    : base(routeName, routeValues) {
                    this.url = url;
                }

                private readonly UrlHelper url;

                public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
                    if (context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
                        string destinationUrl = url.RouteUrl(base.RouteName, base.RouteValues);
                        JavaScriptResult result = new JavaScriptResult()
                        {
                            Script = "window.location='" + destinationUrl + "';"
                        };
                        result.ExecuteResult(context);
                    } else {
                        base.ExecuteResult(context);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```